# What is the precise meaning of 'break-after' in an XSL-FO document?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I'm trying to figure out best to describe the influence the attribute `break-after` has on the layout of a two-column page with multiple paragraphs:

```
<fo:block text-align="justify" font-size="14pt" break-after="column">
    <fo:block space-after="0.1in">In 294 BC, the people...</fo:block>
    <fo:block space-after="0.1in">The Colossus was built...</fo:block>
    <fo:block space-after="0.1in">The statue was toppled....</fo:block>
    <fo:block space-after="0.1in">The statue remained on....</fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

---

If I had only seen the page generated by this code (and not the code itself), and was asked to describe the layout algorithm I'd simply say *it fills up the first column with as much text as possible, before placing the remaining text in the second column.*

[image]

To my eyes this pretty much describes what's going on, but I can't reconcile this description with the meaning of `break-after="column"`. For example `break-after` suggests to me that column breaks should only occur *after* a paragraph, but this clearly isn't what happens - in this small document they frequently occur in the middle of paragraphs.

Can anyone describe this layout algorithm more precisely, and with reference to the precise meaning of `break-after="column"`?

> Here are the [documents](http://jmp.sh/xILCyBV) I'm using (.fo file, and the pdf it generates). Note that the materials come from the book *XML: QuickStart Guide* by Kevin Howard Goldberg

Comment: I would say it means the when the container you have specified it on ends ("after"), then "break" to the next column. That could be another column in the same page for multi-columns or it could be the next page if the last column. The effect you see in your picture is that the content after the block you specified that property on begins on the next page as the end of it was inside the second column of two -columns on the page. A property like "break-*" has nothing to do will fill this or that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be specific against your sample, your question and what you ask ... the "block" of things that has the break-after="column" applied is a block that contains four additional blocks inside of it.

The addition of break-after="column" on this container block means literally, "break to the next column at the end of this block." So in your case, you have those four blocks flowing along (whether or not those four blocks of content cause their own column breaks or not is of no matter). They are flowing into a two-column layout because (obviously) your page has two columns specified for the flow region.

When the formatter finished those flour blocks of content, the last of which starts with "The statue remained on...." it finished the content of the containing block on which you specified break-after="column".

So, the formatter injected a column-break for additional content. In this case, you were in the second column of the two-column layout so breaking to the next column means going to the next page. So content following that block started in the top of the next column.

The property break-after="column" has nothing to do with flowing here or there or anything, it is only instructing the formatter that at the end of element on which I am specified, jump to the next column and put down more things. It is not inherited, does not in any way change the behavior of the children.

If you wish to simplify it to the nth degree ... it really mean when you encounter the </block> on which I am specified, jump to the next column and start with more content.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - I'm surprised to hear that it's not inherited. From the book I'm working through I'd picked up the impression that all attributes were inherited by a block's children - are you saying that for some attributes this isn't the case?

Comment: Some are and some are not. For example font information is but breaks are not. The standard itself details which are inherited. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#common-font-properties and look at font-family, it states inherited.

Answer (score -2):

"*it fills up the first column with as much text as possible, before placing the remaining text in the second column.*" is pretty much what happens.  The work of turning characters into glyphs, assembling glyphs into lines, and fitting lines into block areas, and breaking block areas across pages is left up to the XSL Formatter.  The role of the properties in your FO is to specify constraints that the XSL Formatter has to also follow.  For example, `page-width` and `page-heights` are constraints on page size (and they're included in the 'Constraints' section in https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_simple-page-master).

The keep-* and break-* properties are also constraints that the XSL Formatter has to follow.  The details of how they apply and interact is in Section 4.8, Keeps and Breaks, of XSL 1.1 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keepbreak).  When you don't specify a break, no break will be forced, and the XSL Formatter will do its best based on other applicable constraints.  That is, the default value for both `break-before` and `break-after` is `auto`, and the definition of `auto` for `break-before` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#break-before) is "No break shall be forced".  The definition also has this note:

> Page breaks may occur as determined by the formatter's processing as affected by the "widow", "orphan", "keep-with-next", "keep-with-previous", and "keep-together" properties.